# Java Libgdx - Box2d setTransform multiple bodies with joints

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, box2d-joints

I have a group of body, attached with some joints (wheel-joint, prismatic-joint, revolute-joint)

I'm trying to move that group of body to a position with the method setTransform

I decided to move only one body to the position, and others bodies should follow because of joints.

I'm getting a weird result, the bodies start to roll, move to nowhere, a real weird result, here is some image to explain :

[image]

**How to move multiple bodies attached with joints, to a position using setTransform ?**

Note : there is no obstacle thru the object, from point A to point B (moving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a box2d setTransform() reference:

> Set the position of the body's origin and rotation. This breaks any contacts and wakes the other bodies. Manipulating a body's transform may cause non-physical behavior.

I think that the problem is just the mechanism you are trying to use to move body and the setTransform is not the right way.

Instead of this consider using

```
void com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body.setLinearVelocity(Vector2 v)
```

you can calculate **v** as a subtraction of end point and start point of the body. You should handle stopping body (by zeroing its velocity) when it will reach the target.

Please notice that **setLinearVelocity** does not depend on you gravity

---

Second solution is just to setTransform to all bodies in this "joint group". You can iterate over bodies and move them depends on their start position and the target vector

```
for(Body body : jointGroup)
{
    body.setTransform(body.getPosition.x - someX, ...)
    ...
```

Comment: I made bodies and joint with a software called Rube, I import them and trying to set there respawn position in my game, that's why I think setTransform is the aproprieted method for my case

Comment: then maybe try to apply **setTransform** to all bodies in this "joint-group"? Something like


for(Body body : bodiesInJointGroup){ body.setTransform( body.getPosition.x - someX, ... ) }

Comment: I think that might be the answer, I will try that as soon as possible and tell you if it works. Write it as an answer in case that works

Comment: it works you can write this as answer I will valid it